# shared element transition is not working when using toolbar home

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I'm currently running into a strange problem, similar to here [Shared element transition when using ActionBar Back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713793/shared-element-transition-when-using-actionbar-back-button) but with a fragment to fragment shared element transition. It works fine when using the back button. As soon as the toolbar home is triggered it's just blinking. So calling finishAfterTransition() is no option here.

I call the same method both times. The base for back navigation

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

      if (coordinator != null) {
         coordinator!!.back()
      } else {
         finish()
      }
   }
```

and the intercepted toolbar home click.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
      return when (item?.itemId) {
         android.R.id.home -> {
            onBackPressed()
            true
         }
         else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
      }
   }
```

**Update:** Now I noted like one out of ten tries it works correctly.

I hope anyone of you guys has a clue why this happens.
Regards coffeelord

Comment: The action bar button is due to setting a parent Activity or a simple button ?

Comment: @Pankaj Sati: I'm not sure what you mean. As far it's just a simple back button returning to the first fragment